# Is it possible in GraphQL to structure a Query to expect an Integer, or an array of Integers?

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I have a feeling that it must be strongly typed, one way or the other, and am curious if I can accomplish both with the same query, I would want to something like this:

```
{
  accounts(accountId: [1,2,3]) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And also be able to make this same call treating it as a plain int:

```
{
  accounts(accountId: 1) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A List is a wrapping type that *wraps* another type, but it is a distinct type in itself. So `Int` and `[Int]` are two different types. A field or argument must have exactly one type, so it can only have the type `Int` *or* the type `[Int]` -- not both.

However, you can exploit how GraphQL coerces List input values. From the spec:

> If the value passed as an input to a list type is not a list and not the null value, then the result of input coercion is a list of size one, where the single item value is the result of input coercion for the list’s item type on the provided value (note this may apply recursively for nested lists).

In other words, if the type of the `accountId` is `[Int]` (or `[Int!]` or `[Int!]!`), the client can still pass in a single integer as a value instead of an array. In this case, the value will be *coerced* into an array with a single value (the one that was passed in).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Daniel Reardon's answer: unfortunately, it's not possible to query for the same field with different arguments.  The recommended technique for that situation would be to use aliases:

https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases

However, you can design your API to return different results based on the array you're passing to it.  So for example, you could return only one record if there is only one item in the array, many if there are many, or all records if the array is empty.

Here's some hypothetical code of what that might look like:

```
public IEnumerable<Accounts> GetAccounts(int[] accountIds)
{
    // if no items in array
    if (accountIds.Length == 0)
    {
        // return all accounts
        return Accounts.ToList();
    }

    // return only accounts that are in accountIds array
    // if only one item is in array, then an IEnumerable with only one item will be returned
    return Accounts
        .Where(b => accountIds.Contains(b.AccountId))
        .ToList();
}
```

[Hot Chocolate's GetCharacters(int[] ids) method in the Star Wars API example](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate-examples/blob/master/PureCodeFirst/Repositories/CharacterRepository.cs) will also return only a single character if an array with only one ID is passed or many if there are multiple items in the array:

```
public IEnumerable<ICharacter> GetCharacters(int[] ids)
        {
            foreach (int id in ids)
            {
                if (_characters.TryGetValue(id, out ICharacter? c))
                {
                    yield return c;
                }
            }
        }
```